# turn back html element to its original location, after translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm using

```
document.getElementById('Droping1').style['-webkit-transform'] = translate(0px,'+Ground+'px)';
```

to move an html object.

How should I send it back to it's original place for reusing. 
I don't want the user to see the translate back.

My solution is:

```
document.getElementById(event.data.name).style['-webkit-transition'] = '0s';    
document.getElementById(event.data.name).style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(0px)';
```

Is there a better solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

first of all save the current `style['-webkit-transform']` value in a temp variable, then after the translation assign it back to `style['-webkit-transform']` like this:

```
var temp = document.getElementById('Droping1').style['-webkit-transform'];
document.getElementById('Droping1').style['-webkit-transform'] = translate(0px,'+Ground+'px)';
```

after:

```
document.getElementById('Droping1').style['-webkit-transform'] = temp;
```

in order to not show the client the translation to original position you should set `-webkit-transition-duration` property to `0s` before `document.getElementById('Droping1').style['-webkit-transform'] = temp;` in order to take place in the blink of an eye like the way you change `-webkit-transform` property using JS.

Comment: thank you. it works. but i wonder is it the best way to reset element position?

Comment: @RonyArbiv, Yes its a common way to do it.

Comment: thanks again. the problem i still have is that the tranlete back shown on the screen. i want to prevent the elemnt shown at the way back to its original place.

Comment: @RonyArbiv, can you give me a jsFiddle please?

Comment: thanks. i can't upload the code, it's belong to my work. i am using    "-webkit-transition:6s;" in the css file.  then when i use                       document.getElementById('Droping1').style['-webkit-transform'] = temp; it's get back to it's original place in 6s.

Comment: @RonyArbiv, so if my answer helped you fix the problem, please check it as accepted.thanks.

Comment: thanks friend. i am sorry but your answer didnt fix my problem. the user can still see the img transform, and i don't want him to see it. to fix this i use 0s. the the translate is fast. but i don't like this solution, thats what i am asking. thanks again for your time. (if i will check your answer as accepted no one else will help me.)